# Unity воспроизведение отрезков звука из одного файла mp3

Tags: unity3d

День добрый!

Столкнулся с необходимостью воспроизведения клипов из одного большого файла mp3. есть к нему json с разметкой - начала и окончания в мл секундах воспроизведения , к тому же есть клипы с поддержкой loop. В игре присутствует несколько source audio с которыми должны быть связаны свои аудиофайлы , которые каждый представляет массив клипов. Есть ли методы unity использовать такие файлы или необходимо каждый аудио файл массив клипов порезать на отдельные файлы клипов?

Спасибо